# Sending and retrieving a constant field

Tags: filemaker

I'm using Filemaker 11 to manage content over Custom Web publishing, with a json xslt sheet to convert the XML to a json format is there any way to add a parameter to the url, and have it come back down without modifying it?

I thought about globals, but from what I can tell if two requests were sent within a short enough amount of time, there could be a race condition, one overwriting the others global..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters are passed to the stylesheet in `<xsl:param name="request-query" />`, whose structure must be specified in the documentation, but as far as I remember it's

```
<query action="..."> <-- the form action, i.e. the url -->
  <parameter name="...">...</parameter>
</query>
```

The `query` namespace is `http://www.filemaker.com/xml/query`. FileMaker's own idea of passing custom parameters is to name them like `token.1`, etc., but it's possible to pass just any set of parameters to a XSLT that uses a `process` action (i.e. doesn't hit the database), sort the parameters out into what goes into the db and what stays, make an inline call, and then process the result and add the saved parameters back.

Note that you also can access the cookies and the headers, if you need. Also note that XSLT API is deprecated and won't be supported in future FileMaker version.

Comment: Do you have a link about it being deprecated? My boss said he thought he remembered hearing about that, but couldn't remember where

Comment: Sure: http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/7701/~/deprecation-of-xslt-api-for-custom-web-publishing